# Local HTML validator (Ubuntu)

Tags: html, validation

What local HTML validators are available for Ubuntu? 
I've tried to to Google it but found nothing.

Which validator can be used locally on the command line?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend installing tidy:

```
sudo apt-get install tidy
```

Then read the man page:

```
man tidy
```

Comment: While Tidy is an HTML code checker, I don't think it was ever meant as a full validation tool.

Comment: https://www.html-tidy.org/